# How to rename y axes in Google Charts API?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to rename the labels on the axes to levels like low|medium| high instead of percentages in my bar chart. Could anyone suggest me a way of accomplishing it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Programming Languages', 'Expertise Level %'],
            ['Java', 100],
            ['C', 80],
            ['Python', 100],
            ['Web UX', 100],
            ['Matlab', 70]

        ]);

        var options = {
            bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        };

      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, no option available for *Material* charts...

many options are not supported, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

however, using a *Classic* chart, the `vAxis.ticks` option can be used to customize the axis labels...

use the formatted value of each tick to display --> `Low, Medium, High`

```
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 33.33, f: 'Low'},
        {v: 66.67, f: 'Medium'},
        {v: 100, f: 'High'}        
      ]
    }
```

see following working snippet,

which also uses option --> `theme: 'material'`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Programming Languages', 'Expertise Level %'],
    ['Java', 100],
    ['C', 80],
    ['Python', 100],
    ['Web UX', 100],
    ['Matlab', 70]
  ]);

  var options = {
    theme: 'material',
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 33.33, f: 'Low'},
        {v: 66.67, f: 'Medium'},
        {v: 100, f: 'High'}        
      ]
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('barchart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barchart"></div>
```

note:

*Material* --> `google.charts.Bar`

*Classic* --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart`

Comment: thanks for suggesting this answer, this will work fine for me.